# IgGrid - How to connect custom feature chooser to the grid?

Tags: infragistics, ignite-ui

In my project I use igGrid from ignite-ui. In headers of columns there are gears. If user clicks gear then a popover apears (feature chooser). My task is to implement custom feature chooser - when user clicks on the gear then my custom feature chooser should apear instead of the built-in feature chooser.

I know how to implement the custom feature chooser and options like sorting, grouping, column moving etc. The problem is that I can't find out how to overwrite the gear click event.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll have to find the gear icons and unbind `mousedown` event to prevent feature chooser to pop up.
After that you can bind to `mousedown` using custom handler to show the custom feature chooser.

```
rendered: function(e, ui) {
    ui.owner.headersTable()
    .find("a[data-fc-button]")
    .off("mousedown")
    .on("mousedown", (e) => {
        //open your own featurechooser here
    });
},
```

Here's a fiddle to demonstrate this - http://jsfiddle.net/dkamburov/da276b5w